# Powershell override of the parent class constructor

Tags: powershell, oop, inheritance, constructor

What is the syntax to completely override a parent constructor?

In the code below I create an Animals class and a Dogs class that inherits from the Animals class.  The Dogs class has its' own constructor but instead of replacing the Animals constructor, it is running both the Animals constructor and the Dogs constructor when instantiating the class.

```
class Animals {
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$animalList = @()
    Animals() {
        $this.animalList.add("moose")
        $this.animalList.add("elephant")
        $this.animalList.add("buffalo")
    }
    showAnimals() {
        foreach($animal in $this.animalList) {
            Write-Host $animal
        }
    }
}
class Dogs : Animals {
    Dogs() {
        $this.animalList.add("Doberman")
        $this.animalList.add("Golden Retriever")
    }
}

$someAnimals = New-Object Animals
$someDogs = New-Object Dogs
Write-Host "The animals list:"
$someAnimals.showAnimals()
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "The dogs list:"
$someDogs.showAnimals()
```

This produces the following:

```
The animals list:
moose
elephant
buffalo

The dogs list:
moose
elephant
buffalo
Doberman
Golden Retriever
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a method into your constructor and override this method into derived class. Like this :

```
class Animals {
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$animalList = @()
    Animals() 
    {
        $this.addAnimals()
    }

    [void] addAnimals() 
    {
        $this.animalList.add("moose")
        $this.animalList.add("elephant")
        $this.animalList.add("buffalo")
    }

    [void] showAnimals() {
        foreach($animal in $this.animalList) {
            Write-Host $animal
        }
    }
}

class Dogs : Animals {

    [void] addAnimals() 
    {
        $this.animalList.add("Doberman")
        $this.animalList.add("Golden Retriever")
    }
}


Write-Host ""
Write-Host ""

$someAnimals = New-Object Animals
Write-Host "The animals list:"
$someAnimals.showAnimals()
Write-Host ""

$someDogs = New-Object Dogs
Write-Host "The dogs list:"
$someDogs.showAnimals()
```